# pg_dump permission denied for sequence

Tags: postgresql, permissions, amazon-rds, pg-dump

I have a strange issue with dumping `post-data` section.

Dump command is:

```
pg_dump -Fc --verbose --section=post-data --no-owner --no-acl -h localhost -p 9999 -U root db_name -W > constraints.dump
```

Here is an error message:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for relation verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT sequence_name, start_value, increment_by, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND max_value = 9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND max_value = -1 THEN NULL      ELSE max_value END AS max_value, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND min_value = 1 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND min_value = -9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      ELSE min_value END AS min_value, cache_value, is_cycled FROM verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq
```

But when I'm trying to execute this query in `psql` it works well:

```
db_name=>  SELECT sequence_name, start_value, increment_by, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND max_value = 9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND max_value = -1 THEN NULL      ELSE max_value END AS max_value, CASE WHEN increment_by > 0 AND min_value = 1 THEN NULL      WHEN increment_by < 0 AND min_value = -9223372036854775807 THEN NULL      ELSE min_value END AS min_value, cache_value, is_cycled FROM verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq;
             sequence_name             | start_value | increment_by | max_value | min_value | cache_value | is_cycled 
---------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------
 verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq |           1 |            1 |           |           |           1 | f
(1 row)
```

Here are the permissions granted to user `root`

```
db_name=> \dg root
                        List of roles
 Role name |          Attributes           |    Member of    
-----------+-------------------------------+-----------------
 root      | Create role, Create DB       +| {rds_superuser}
           | Password valid until infinity |
```

I granted default privileges, select and all to all tables and sequences in schema public but with no luck.

Could you assist please?
Thanks in advnce!

**UPDATE**

```
db_name=> \dp verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq
                                              Access privileges
 Schema |                 Name                  |   Type   | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies 
--------+---------------------------------------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
 public | verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq | sequence | root=rwU/root     |                   | 
(1 row)
```

I'm using an Amazon RDS.

Comment: How about `\dp verification_code_user_mapping_id_seq` ?

Comment: Sorry, for delay. Please check updated section of the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might be an AWS-RDS specific issue but it works if you explicitly specify the schema to be dumped.

`pg_dump -f lol.sql -Fc -v -n public -O -x --section=post-data -h 127.0.0.1 -p 9999 -U root db-name`

Comment: I have PostGIS installed and this was the only solution that worked for me. One cannot even exclude all of the tables that RDS says I don't have access to, it ignores your excludes and then fails to get permission to dump those tables. I should also note that the tables I don't have permission to access _are in_ the schema I'm specifying, but for some reason, now, without even explicitly excluding those tables it works. woof.

Comment: Selecting only the schema to be backed up (rather than all schemas) also worked for Azure hosted Postgres

Comment: I set the schema in my pg_dump command as mentioned and it still didn't work. I had configured my RDS databse through Terraform to create a read-only user for performing pg_dumps. I just needed to add another `postgresql_grant`  with select privilege on the `sequence` object type in the public schema. Related to: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cyrilgdn/postgresql/latest/docs/resources/postgresql_grant?ref=blog.ippon.fr#object_type

Answer (score -2):

My guess that this is simply a permission issue towards the object that is attempted to be dumped. Excluding the sequence would work fine for pg_dump to continue.